# How can I convert a ppt to a pdf from the command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, conversion

I have a folder containing a bunch of ppts, each of which I'd like to convert to an individual pdf.

Comment: I think you meant "a folder containing a bunch of ppts" not pdfs.

Comment: Your question need better explanation. Are you trying to convert each ppt to a pdf, or all the ppts to a single pdf with different pages, or ...?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can use [unoconv](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/). It's available in the repositories, so you can just `apt-get` it: [unoconv](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unoconv) ([direct install link](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/unoconv))

Note that the info in the web page is outdated. Use man or type `unoconv -h` to get actual command line options. It works like this:

```
unoconv -f pdf presentation.odt
```

This command will create a presentation.pdf file.

I have only used it to batch convert ods to pdf and it works perfectly. I haven't tried it with presentations (but for a quick test now), but I expect that it will work nicely.

Note that it will not work on Lucid (10.04), because of a bug in the `python-openoffice` biddings. If you need to use it on Lucid, you can add this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~openoffice-pkgs/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=lucid) to your software sources to upgrade your Openoffice version.

Comment: Your example uses the wrong command (`uniconv` instead of `unoconv`)

Comment: That gives this error: Leaking python objects bridged to UNO for reason pyuno runtime is not initialized, (the pyuno.bootstrap needs to be called before using any uno classes)
Segmentation fault

Comment: @James: Yes, I checked it on 10.04 and it gives that error. A little googling shows that there is a bug in the Openoffice version shipped with Lucid. It works on Maverick (10.10) and Hardy (8.04), the versions that I use.

Comment: For anyone wondering how to convert a folder containing any type of documents (*.txt, *.docx, *.pptx and even *.pdf etc) to PDFs : `unoconv -f pdf <input-folder-path>/* --output <output-folder-path>/*`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a great solution!

Answer (score 109):

You can also use the **command line** of **libreoffice** for your purpose. This example converts all ppt-files in the current directory to pdf's:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --convert-to pdf *.ppt
```

> --headless
>   Starts in "headless mode", which allows using the application without a user interface.
>          This special mode can be used when the application is controlled by external clients via the API...
>   It  implies  --invisible  and  strictly ignores any GUI environment.

and

> --invisible
>               Starts in invisible mode.
>                 Neither the start-up logo nor the initial program window will be visible.  LO can be controlled and documents and dialogs can be opened via the API.
>      When  started with this parameter, it can only be quit using the taskmanager (Windows) or the kill command
>                 (UNIX based systems).

Get more information on command line options with:

```
man libreoffice
```

(Note: You have to close all running instances of LibreOffice before the command line works.)

Comment: This solved my problem.

Comment: It's awesome that libreoffice has the `--convert-to` option, but it sucks that it doesn't say anywhere that you also have to pass `--headless` and `--invisible` for it to work. +1 for the answer.

Comment: `--headless` implies `--invisible` (at least on LO 3.4).  Add `-env:UserInstallation="file://$HOME/.libreoffice-alt"` to work even with GUI instances running (credit [here](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1686/how-to-not-connect-to-a-running-instance/?answer=1701#post-id-1701)).

Comment: (: - Amazing! - :)

Comment: If someone reading this and not using ubuntu, and libreoffice still asks you for X server, you might need libreoffice-headless package installed

Comment: Better to use this if you have libreoffice installed. no need to install anything extra. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Tapper the explanation of the arguments used in the command makes the answer more useful and clear.

Comment: @Melebius instead of "without a user interface" there is "without user a interface" in man page that made me confused. Is there any way to inform this to authority?

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal According to http://www.libreoffice.org/get-help/feedback/, you could create a bug report.

Comment: FWIW, on `MacOS`, `libreoffice` binary is called `soffice` and is located in `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS`

Comment: @ijoseph's tip for MacOS users works for me on 10.13.4

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 too.

Comment: I have tried this solution on my VPS server running Cent OS 7 but getting this error : Error: source file could not be loaded. but the same command is working great if I execute this for .doc file at the same location. any help / idea

Comment: I have executed this command 'yum install unoconv ' after this executed the same script and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This seems like a more stable solution as unoconv often does not work right out of the box, and you have to fiddle with config files.

Comment: worked on ubuntu 21.10; props to libreoffice for the command line tools. This was extremely helpful

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to convert .ppt files to PDF is to install unoconv through the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install unoconv
```

Then open the terminal from the drive where the ppt files are available.
Now type:

```
unoconv -f [format] pdf  filename.ppt
```

That's all. Done.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, This is a Q&A site not a forum. Thank you sharing knowledge but no need to duplicate answers. The high voted answer already mentioned `unoconv` tool.

Comment: Thank you (y) (y) (y)

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy cheat.

Use `unoconv` with `midnight commander` to convert `odt` to `pdf`:

- launch `mc`
- navigate where the `odt` files are
- tag `odt` files using `Ctrl-T` then `F2,@,`
- paste in `unoconv -f pdf`

It will spew a bunch of dire error messages, but it works!