# Bash Script: How to get file name/path

Tags: bash

Suppose I want to associate PPT files to be opened with a bash script that converts it to PDF then opens it with the approperiate PDF editor. How do I do that?

Conversion will be done with uniconv as I learnt from [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11130/how-can-i-convert-a-ppt-to-a-pdf-from-the-command-line)

```
uniconv -f pdf presentation.odt
```

I believe I have to change "presentation.odt" with the filename that triggered this script

Comment: You might get more answers (or better answers) on the [Unix and Linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or on [Stackoverflow.](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean that the script will be called with (for example) `presentation.odt` as an argument? The argument is available as `"$1"` in the script (the double quotes are required if the file name contains characters like spaces which the shell would otherwise expand). You can construct the name of the PDF file by stripping away the `.odt` suffix: `${1%.odt}`. Note that it's `unoconv`, not the unrelated `uniconv`.

```
#!/bin/sh
unoconv -f pdf "$1"
appropriate-pdf-editor "${1%.odt}.pdf"
```

Comment: `appropriate-pdf-editor` could be `xdg-open` to use whichever pdf viewer is currently set as default.

Answer (score 1):

In a shell script, you can access command line parameters through the variable 1, 2, 3, ..., as in

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"
# ...
```

If you need it, "$0" represents the script name itself.

You can also reassign these variable, and `shift` them, to access more than 9 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all `.odt` files and feed them into `unoconv`, you can use the `find` tool to find all of them, then pipe it into `xargs`, which can do parallel processing.

```
find * -type f -iname "*.odt" | xargs -i -P12 "uniconv -f pdf {}"
```

This will `find` all files in the running directory, recurssively, piping files that it finds into `xargs`, which will run up to 12 processes silmultaneously (use `-P0` for unlimited processes).